# Issue with org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was following [BAELDUNG](https://www.baeldung.com/java-okhttp-download-binary-file) download with binary.  So I was figuring out,

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH;
```

It will work with this dependency,

```
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux:5.1.9.RELEASE'
```

In the dependencies list, it will not even show the dependency but errors will go away, the problem is that if I run, I will have this error,

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration$WebFluxConfig.configureResourceCaching(WebFluxAutoConfiguration.java:212)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.web.reactive.config.ResourceHandlerRegistration.setUseLastModified(Z)Lorg/springframework/web/reactive/config/ResourceHandlerRegistration;

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration$WebFluxConfig, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users (not exist)
```

Do I have to download that jar/HttpHeaders manually to work?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot are you using a servlet container of so just add `spring-boot-starter-web` and remove the `webflux` dependency. Also that tutorial you linked to doesn' include anything Spring related so not sure what you are "following" from that tutorial?

Comment: Thanks [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) that works.